# How to restrict users on changing their wallpapers?

Tags: desktop-background, gnome-classic

I don't want my users to change the system wallpaper. How do I the lock the wallpaper down?

#### Update

- Users are changing wallpaper by right clicking the picture and choosing set as wallpaper. How to restrict this behaviour?
- Is it possible to remove Backgrounds Tab from Appearance Preferences? If yes how?

[image]

Comment: OK, so you want them to be able to open images but NOT be able to set them as wallpaper? Also, do they need access to "Settings" (`gnome-control-center`)?

Comment: @izx Yes they need access to settings but should not able to set them as wallpaper.

Comment: ubuntu 10.10 and gnome-classic desktop environment.

Comment: @karthick87 - the background tab is drawn by /usr/share/gnome-control-center/ui/appearance.ui (search for "background" in that file)  .... I've had a quick look, but not sure as yet which bits to edit to hide the tab.  I'll have a look a bit more in depth when I find some time.  Thanks.

Comment: @karthick87 - ok - not quite removal of the tab - but updated my answer for this tab functionality to do nothing.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### eog (eye-of-gnome)

*11.04 and previous versions of ubuntu*

When you mentioned that you can right-click an image and set as wallpaper, this answer assumes you meant - open the jpeg image into eog, right-click and choose "set as desktop background".

[image]

With this answer, you can remove this option:

[image]

With this assumption in mind, you can remove the menu-option AND right-click option by either editing the source directly (if you want to distribute a package) or on a per-client modify the GTK window data.

**solution 1 - edit GTK window data**

First backup the GTK window data:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/eog/eog-ui.xml ~/
gksudo gedit /usr/share/eog/eog-ui.xml
```

Now search for "wallpaper" - delete each line that contains this keyword and save.

To revert the changes:

```
sudo cp ~/eog-ui.xml /usr/share/eog
```

**solution 2 - distribute deb package**

This can be done with this recipe:

```
apt-get source eog
sudo apt-get build-dep eog
sudo apt-get install devscripts
```

If it asks to configure your mail - select *no configuration*

```
cd eog-2*/data
gedit eog-ui.xml
```

Now search for "wallpaper" - delete each line that contains this keyword.

Save.

```
cd ..
gedit debian/changelog
```

add `+ppakarthick` to the first line so that it reads something like:

`eog (2.32.1-0ubuntu2+ppakarthick) natty; urgency=low`

```
debuild -us -uc
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i eog_*.deb
```

Note  - there is only one deb package to install - either 32bit or 64bit depending upon the ubuntu architecture you have installed.  The other deb's produce is a debug package and a development package, both of which you can ignore.

To revert the changes:

```
sudo apt-get purge eog
sudo apt-get install eog
```

This will remove the complete eog package.  Then, the second command will re-download from the repositories, the current eog package.

Note - it may want to remove the meta package `ubuntu-desktop`.  The only affect this has is if you intend to upgrade to Natty.  If you want to upgrade, simply install `ubuntu-desktop` before the upgrade.

#### Gnome-Control-Center background tab

The GTK Window data for this tab is in the file `/usr/share/gnome-control-center/ui/appearance.ui` but I have not found a convenient place in this file that you can hide the background tab itself.

[image]

With a source-code change - you can get the background tab and its buttons to both not display wallpaper and do nothing when the buttons are clicked.

This solution is very similar to solution 2 above.

```
apt-get source gnome-control-center
sudo apt-get build-dep gnome-control-center
sudo apt-get install devscripts
```

If it asks to configure your mail - select *no configuration*

```
cd gnome*/capplets/appearance
gedit appearance-desktop.c
```

Now look for the following function and add `return;` as shown:

```
void
desktop_init (AppearanceData *data,
          const gchar **uris)
{
  GtkWidget *add_button, *w;
  GtkCellRenderer *cr;
  char *url;

  data->wp_update_gconf = TRUE;

  data->wp_uris = NULL;

  return;
```

Save.

```
cd ../..
gedit debian/changelog
```

add `+ppakarthick` to the first line so that it reads something like:

`gnome-control-center (1:2.30.1-0ubuntu2+ppakarthick) lucid-proposed; urgency=low`

```
debuild -us -uc
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i capplets*.deb
sudo dpkg -i libgnome-window-settings1*.deb
sudo dpkg -i gnome-control-center_*.deb
```

To revert the changes:

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome-control-center libgnome-window-settings1 capplets-data
sudo apt-get install ubuntu_desktop
```

This will remove the complete gnome-control-center package and a few other packages.  Then, the second command will re-download from the repositories, all the packages previously removed.

Comment: Error on `debuild -us -uc` here is the error http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1040147/

Comment: each one of those "unmet dependencies" should have been installed when you did `sudo apt-get build-dep gnome-control-center` - what happens if you install these individually e.g. `sudo apt-get install libxss-dev` and `sudo apt-get install libgnome-menu-dev` etc etc.?

Answer (score 7):

There are two ways that I know of:
1. As root run gconf-editor: `gksudo gconf-editor`.  In the left pane find `/ desktop / gnome / background`.  On the right panel, find `picture_filename`, right click on it and select `Set as Mandatory`. 
2. Another way is to simply prevent normal users from executing the wallpaper changer by running (as root): `chmod 744 /usr/bin/gnome-appearance-properties`

Comment: gconf-editor is what i want. Is is possible to set that option `Set as Mandatory` from terminal? So that i can make a script and execute it in all hosts.

Comment: One possibility is the user opens the wallpaper and right click and set as wallpaper applies the wallpaper. Any way to restrict this ?

Answer (score 7):

The command line version of Mark's answer would be:

```
sudo gconftool-2 --direct --config-source xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.mandatory --type string --set /desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename "/usr/share/backgrounds/Tri_Narwhal_by_momez.jpg"
```

Comment: I have done this, but how to revert it back?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to easily set the wallpaper (desktop background) at each login.  Create a new login program in "Startup Applications" with the following command.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///usr/share/backgrounds/edubuntu_default.png"
```

Of course you can specify any image simply by replacing "edubuntu_default.png" with your image.