# How to block the desktop background from being changed?

Tags: 12.04, unity, desktop-background

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to restrict users on changing their wallpapers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36276/how-to-restrict-users-on-changing-their-wallpapers)

I'm trying to lock the desktop background *(So, that it cannot be changed by others)* but can not find the way, I got it in 10.04 with "gconf-editor", but now I can not do this in 12.04

Comment: Are you talking about **LOCK SCREEN** feature.

Comment: No, i'm talking about the DESKTOP BACKGROUND, i want that user can't change it

Comment: You can refer this http://askubuntu.com/questions/36276/how-to-restrict-users-on-changing-their-wallpapers

Comment: I solved part but not all, THANKS!!

Answer (score -1):

Besides the list of solutions which can answer your question which can be found [to this similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36276/how-to-restrict-users-on-changing-their-wallpapers).

Another way to achieve that is the following:

Open terminal and login as root:

```
sudo -i
```

Type:

```
chmod 744 /usr/bin/ gnome-appearance-properties
```

To restore:

```
chmod 755 /usr/bin/gnome-appearance-properties
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i have a problem i got not installed "gnome-appearance-properties", i'm working with Unity not with gnome... I resolve the problem changing the wallpaper from desktop, but now the problem is i can change it from firefox

Comment: did you try restoring it?

Comment: Sorry, but restoring what????

Comment: restore "gnome-appearance-properties" by typing the second command

Comment: i got not installed "gnome-appearance-properties", or  in my /usr/bin & /usr/sbin don't appear. In 10.04 y solved the problem with gconf-editor, but 12.04 it don't works. But with the @tijybba reply i solve almost completely, the firefox part i solve with a addon called "menu-editor", is not the best way to solve it, but works!!