# Blocking users from changing wallpaper

Tags: 14.04, permissions, desktop-background

I am currently running Ubuntu Gnome 14.04. I wanted to stop users from changing their wallpaper, so i followed this guide: [How to block the desktop background from being changed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165448/how-to-block-the-desktop-background-from-being-changed)

After I ran the first command, all windows in my session closed, then the terminal closed. I logged out and logged back in and still couldn't do anything. So I logged in as root and tried running the second command. The terminal comes back with a message saying the file doesn't exist. I browsed to /usr/bin and the file is not there. What do I do? I can only login as root(and I don't want to do that) Is there a way for me to retrieve that file? Can someone upload their unmodified file so that I could place the file back and chmod it to 755? I need some quick help as I will soon need my account for a school presentation.

Comment: Why do you need to block it changing?

Comment: Umm the command you ran there was wrong, you have changed the permissions of all of `/usr`, all of `/usr/bin` and so on...

Comment: Thats not the point I don't care about locking the wallpaper anymore. I just want to fix what I messed up

Comment: I don't think you can, that command was bad.

Comment: I fixed it.  I ran 'chmod 755 /usr && chmod 755 /usr/bin' (as root). Thanks Tim, even though you didn't tell me how to fix it you told me that /usr and /usr/bin were set to permission 744.

Comment: The command had space between `/usr/bin/` and `gnome-appearance-properties`,  so chmod has treated those as two different entries. Command itself was not bad, it was just written incorrectly

Comment: @Serg it had spaces between all the file names... I've since fixed it. It was right, but what they had written was dangeous...

Answer (score 0):

OPs answer:

> I fixed it. I ran `chmod 755 /usr && chmod 755 /usr/bin` (as root).
>   Thanks Tim, even though you didn't tell me how to fix it you told me
>   that `/usr` and `/usr/bin` were set to permission 744.