# Password protect changing wallpaper

Tags: password, desktop-background, system-settings

In order to prevent someone (other than me) from changing my background, how can I make wallpaper changing an action requiring a password?

Comment: Is this helping you? http://askubuntu.com/a/445184/72216

Comment: See Jacob's comment. You will most likely not be able to block background changing, but you can definitely protect <insert app name here>.

Comment: I don't really know the command to change wallpapers. My shellscripting skills aren't the best but if you give me the path.

Comment: @Whaaaaaat See comment

Comment: @JacobVlijm See comment

Comment: Is this post of any help? http://askubuntu.com/a/527633/72216 both commands to get the current/set another wallpaper are in the script (cmd1 / cmd2)

Comment: @JacobVlijm Thanks that worked for me. I guess this question us a duplicate, should I delete it?

Comment: @rajlego The question has been mentioned too broad, but not a duplicate as far as I can see. If it is specifically the wallpaper, then probably. If you can make your question more specific to one case? The wallpaper link is not asking for a password :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I block users to change wallpaper (under Unity in Ubuntu 12 and 14)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/527181/how-can-i-block-users-to-change-wallpaper-under-unity-in-ubuntu-12-and-14)

Comment: @muru I thought this question was a duplicate to, except for one difference: I want to be able to change the wallpaper if I want by typing in my password. If you think I'm wrong, please tell me, I will delete the question. But I did as Jacob if this was a duplicate already and I don't think it is based on his response.

Comment: My flag was based on your comment that you "guess this question us a duplicate". If it isn't, sorry.

Comment: @muru no problem, no harm done

Comment: To the latest close-voter: how ever can this be too broad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a nice challenge. Try,

```
$ sudo mv /usr/bin/gsettings /usr/bin/gsettings2
$ sudo gedit /usr/bin/gsettings
$ sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/gsettings
```

When gedit comes up on the second instruction, add:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" == "set" ] && [ "$2" == "org.gnome.desktop.background" ] && [ "$3" == "picture-uri" ]; then
    a=$(zenity --entry="Password")
    h1=$(/bin/echo $a | /usr/bin/md5sum | /bin/cut -f1 -d" ")
    h2='a799d7cf3d9ca647f1320fc6bfaf7408' #Password hash
    if [ "$h1" == "$h2" ]; then
    gsettings2 set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri $4
    else
        zenity --notification --text="Wrong password. Come again another day"
    fi
else
    $(gsettings2 $@)
fi
```

To undo,

```
$ sudo rm /usr/bin/gsettings
$ sudo mv /usr/bin/gsettings2 /usr/bin/gsettings
```

You can go to this [md5 generator](http://www.md5.cz/), put your string and replace `a799d7cf3d9ca647f1320fc6bfaf7408` with whatever you like. Try finding out for yourself what this corresponds. You'll realize how secure this is.

Even if somebody views this file, without your password they cannot change it (This is similar to how linux stores your passwords :P).

Answer (score 2):

#### Password protect changing wallpaper

The script below provides a mild password protection for changing the wallpaper in "home" situations. Mild because the password is stored inside the script in plain text. Nevertheless it should prevent average users from changing the wallpaper.

What it does is that when a user changes the wallpaper, it changes back immediately, and the user is prompted for a password. If the password is correct, the wallpaper changes into the newly set one, otherwise nothing happens.

[image]

To minimize the risk, store the script in an unexpected place under an unexpected name, and /or as a hidden file.

#### To use it:

Copy the script below into an empty file, set a password of your choice in the head section (I wouldn't choose your sudo password for security reasons, since it is in plain text!) and save it as `name.py`, run it by the command:

```
python3 /path/to/name.py
```

#### The script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import time
import subprocess

set_password = "monkey"

key = "org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "
read = "gsettings get "+key; change = "gsettings set "+key
set_wallpaper = subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", read]).decode("utf-8").strip()
pass_window ='zenity --entry --entry-text="Enter password" --text="Enter password" --title="password" --hide-text'

def check_wall():
    global set_wallpaper
    curr_wallpaper = subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", read]).decode("utf-8").strip()
    if curr_wallpaper != set_wallpaper:
        subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", change+set_wallpaper])
        try:
            entered_password = subprocess.check_output(
                ["/bin/bash", "-c", pass_window]).decode("utf-8").strip()
        except Exception:
            entered_password = None
        if entered_password == set_password:
            subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", change+curr_wallpaper])
            set_wallpaper = curr_wallpaper
    else:
        pass

while True:
    check_wall()
    time.sleep(3)
```

---

posted on [gist.gisthub](https://gist.github.com/Jacob-Vlijm/816b64a056ac30d0bafc)

Comment: Why not add a script to change owner of gsettings to root after boot, and share the user and root password. It won't need an infinite loop.

Comment: @prakharsingh95 Although I did try something like that (but it didn't work somehow), in general I prefer to keep the existing configuration and permissions untouched. I chose for a relatively simple script that could be started and stopped on the fly. If you can make it work however, it would be a nice additional answer to this question.