# Disable features for a specific user

Tags: permissions, 15.10, users, desktop-background

I want to disable all features on a specific user, on my Ubuntu 15.10. I want him to:

- Don't change the wallpaper

  - I followed this [How to restrict users on changing their wallpapers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36276/how-to-restrict-users-on-changing-their-wallpapers) , but my ubuntu has no "gnome-appearence..."
  - I found this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2010824 , I'll try it now, let's see if this works. This works, every time the user logs, the wallpaper changes. I'll continue searching for some "chmod" solution.
  - I've chmod 700 unity-control-center. Now there's no settings for any users (only for root)
- Don't let then do anything on the computer, not saving files, not surfing on the directories, not executing any type of program (only the navigator)...
- Make the navigator automatically launch, with a specific home that cant be changed. Either dont let then navigate in other pages.
- Let a custom script (that has the usbip start + bind) execute every time the system loads.

I need to have access to all features in an admin account.

I've created a custom user, and with `sudo nautilus` I disabled access to all the `/` directory. The system crashed, so I only let him his `/home/thenameoftheuser` directory. It crashes too.

Comment: And what do you expect from us?

Comment: Any type of help. For example, where is the "gnome-appearence..." on ubuntu 15.10?

Comment: BTW, sudo + GUI is a bad idea: http://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications

Comment: Didn't know about that, tought typing sudo was like excuting as admin, won't do it again.

Comment: Wallpaper changing can be sort of restricted with putting a function that keeps on setting the wall paper (basically infinite loop). Navigation to other directories is a bit more problematic - there's almost no way to restrict that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's easy!  It's called the [guest session](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-help/shell-guest-session.html)!

Just give that particular user a USB stick to save their files to and you've got picture-perfect isolation **without any additional work**!

If that's not restrictive enough, you can [customise the guest session](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession) with all of your requirements...

#### ;-)

Comment: How can I enable the guest sesion on a live Ubuntu?

Comment: Found this http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-disable-or-enable-guest-account-in-ubuntu-13-04/ , now I have my guesst session enabled and I can start customizing it, thank you!

Comment: Good one!  Reputation 8 user already!